# Exposing WebService APIs to the outside world for universal access

Tags: .net, web-services, api, language-agnostic

I would like to implement an API for my web based service.
I've been looking around at ways to do this, but all the choices seems slightly overwhelming.

- ASP.NET WebService .asmx (Seems okay)
- XML-RPC.NET (I think this one seems good, but not sure if its updated, or needs updating)
- WCF WebService WSDL (Seems really heavy and might not be
  so simple for external users to write
  against if they're not using .NET)
- Something else I am not aware of?

The way I envisage the service to work is that the user calling the api will need to login, and the login function returns some sort of token which needs to be included with each subsequent request.

I would like the service to be easily consumed by any language.

Your thoughts and suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you're needs are but I'll throw this out...
Consider doing a REST-style API
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

The advantage is simplicity, usually the whole backend call can be described in a simple URL.  However you don't want to be pedantic about the "REST way".  (ex. strict REST says "GETS are idempotent).  It also imposes a strict hierarchy of resources.  As long as you're flexible it's still a nice design because you don't need heavy support tools to work with it.

Comment: I was reading about REST as well, although I am not sure how to handle user logins. It seems fine for publicly accessible methods

Comment: The login call itself could be a rest call.  (most of the calls would require sessions except for stuff like login).  Or, you might just have the browser navigate to another page upon successful login

Comment: Ah so using post, including the token as a variable. I see, yeah, that could work. Thanks for the tip.